# Display images in order rather than by random using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, math

Listed below in the block of code is `Math.random`. I'm trying to display images every time the page is refreshed or reloaded. Though, the only way I know is to mathmatically load them randomly. The problem is, I don't want them to load randomly, I want them to load in order of the imageArray. Is there a way around the random function that can display each image in order of the array?

```
var imageArray = [
    [ 'http://example.com/assets/reporter.png', '<style>body{background-image:url(), -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5eddf 0%, #e3cfad 100%);#image{margin-left:500px;}</style>', '' ],
    [ 'http://example.com/assets/chair.png', '<style>body{background-image:url(), -webkit-linear-gradient(#7abbe7 0%, #a7dbfa 100%);}</style>', '' ]

];


function doIt()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length);

    var html = "<a href='"+imageArray[rand][2]+"'><img src='"+imageArray[rand][0]+"' alt='heder' border='0' align='absmiddle' /></a><div>"+imageArray[rand][1]+"</div>";

document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: @Onchie document.cookie="rand="(Math.random() imageArray.length); ?

Comment: Yep, something like that. [Cookie](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm)

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Why can't you use a `for` loop to iterate over the image array and display each image? Do you want to display just one image, but a different image each time you reload the page?

Comment: @Barmar One image is displayed from the list randomly each time the page is loaded. The problem I'm having is that the list is randomly selected and the image might be displayed the same time for a couple of page loads. I don't want that, I'm looking to find a way to get the list to display in order not randomly (imageArray). I've tried doing a loop, but it ends in the same result, random images rather than in order.

Comment: @Onchie It looks like I need the var statement.

Answer (score 0):

Put the array index in a cookie or local storage. When the page loads, get the cookie, and increment it (if it's not set this is the first time, so select an image at random). If the increment reaches the size of the array, wrap around to 0. Then display the image with that index. Then save the new cookie value.

```
var imageArray = [
    [ 'http://example.com/assets/reporter.png', '<style>body{background-image:url(), -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5eddf 0%, #e3cfad 100%);#image{margin-left:500px;}</style>', '' ],
    [ 'http://example.com/assets/chair.png', '<style>body{background-image:url(), -webkit-linear-gradient(#7abbe7 0%, #a7dbfa 100%);}</style>', '' ]

];

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function doIt()
{
    var rand = getCookie('rand');
    if (rand == null) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length);
    } else {
        rand++;
        if (rand >= imageArray.length) {
            rand = 0;
        }
    }
    setCookie('rand', rand);
    var html = "<a href='"+imageArray[rand][2]+"'><img src='"+imageArray[rand][0]+"' alt='heder' border='0' align='absmiddle' /></a><div>"+imageArray[rand][1]+"</div>";

    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = html;
}​
```